# Fluid Simulation: Fluid is not coming from the inflow

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to get fluid pouring from a sphere into this cup. However, when I bake the simulation the fluid also comes dripping down from places further along the x-axis from the sphere. What is causing this and how can I fix it?
I attached a few screenshots of what I mean and the fluid settings for the inflow, domain and obstacle.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly because the domain is too narrow or the fluid is splashing on the sides of the domain?

Comment: I don't have the .blend file anymore because I recently weeded out my blender folder but you could be right. I might've positioned the inflow object outside of the domain slightly. Would that lead to weird stuff like in my old scene?